# StanfordNLP Spanish Tokenizer

Tags: tokenize, stanford-nlp

I want to tokenize a text in Spanish  with StanfordNLP and my problem is that the model splits any word matching the pattern "\d*s " (a word composed by digits and ending with an "s") in two tokens. If the word finished with another letter, such as "e", the tokenizer return only one token.

For instance, given the sentence:
"Vendo iPhone 5s  es libre de fabrica esta nuevo sin usar."

The tokenizer return for the text "iPhone 5s" three tokens:"iPhone", "5" and "s".

Someone has an idea how could I avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are working with the SpanishTokenizer rather than PTBTokenizer.

[SpanishTokenizer](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/international/spanish/process/SpanishTokenizer.html) is heavily based on the [FrenchTokenizer](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/international/french/process/FrenchTokenizer.html), which comes also  from the [PTBTokenizer](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/process/PTBTokenizer.html) (English).

I've run all three with your sentence and seems that the PTBTokenizer give you the results you need, but not the others.

As all of them are deterministic tokenizers I think you can't avoid that problem because seems to me that the problem is not in the heuristic part which should run later after the deterministic.

A possible workaround may be to use [WhitespaceTokenizer](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/process/WhitespaceTokenizer.html), as long as you don't mind having punctuation tokens or some other gramma rules.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I work with the tokenizers used by StanfordCoreNLP.  If I delete the property: props.setProperty("tokenize.language", "es") than the tokenizer returns the expected result, as you said. I don't want to use WhitespaceTokenizer  because it returns words and punctuations in the same token.